How to listen events from flutter webview to flutter
In flutter app, I loaded single page webview that page developed by flutter. while clicking button from flutter webview, it should call flutter code. I used InAppWebView plugin to load flutter webview page.
I expecting listen events from flutter webview to flutter dart code

You can check addJavaScriptChannel() method and in flutter webview, use controller.runJavascript("postMessage('post from flutter')");

addJavaScriptChannel is deprecated

you can call using addJavaScriptHandler() from webview controller.
It gives you parameter callback as args

I do the this in my inappwebview too, so here's my exampe of how to communicate from Javascript to the flutter side.
When you create your inappwebview, in onWebViewCreated setup the javascript handler like so (flutter):
InAppWebView(
    initialUrlRequest: 'https://www.google.com',
    initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
      isInspectable: true,
      javaScriptEnabled: true,
    ),
    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
      webViewControllerObj = controller;
      webViewControllerObj.addJavaScriptHandler(handlerName: 'Flutter', callback: (args) {
      // Handles incoming js messages.
        handleWebMessage(args[0]);
      });
  },
);

I've found that this is the best way to call flutter code and pass in arguments at the same time (js):
window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler(`Flutter`, {'functionName': 'pageLoadData', 'parametersObj': {'langCode': 'en-uk', 'externalUserId': 'user_24_32'}}}); // Replace the functionName and arguments to your use case :)

And to retrieve the function name and parameters (flutter):
Future<void> handleWebMessage(Map<String, dynamic> dataObj) async {
    var parametersJSONObj = dataObj['parametersObj'];
    switch (dataObj['functionName']) {
    // Replace this with your functionNames that you call.
      case 'pageLoadData':
        pageLoadData(parametersJSONObj['pageDataObjStr']); // Replace 'pageDataObjStr' with arguments you pass in.
        break;
      case 'openInbox':
        openInbox(context);
        break;
        .....

Or if there's no parameters you need to pass in, you can just call the handler like so (js):
window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler(`Flutter`, 'pageLoadData'); // Replace 'pageLoadData' to your use case :)

And handle it in Flutter similarly.
Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions - Amy :)
